# Add a DropDownList to the masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

I tried to add a DropdownList to a panel, which I created in the aspx file. In the end, I would like to have a DropDownList, which will be only shown on one page.

This is how I created my panel:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlChannel"></asp:Panel>
```

Then I create the DropdownList inside the codebehind :
The method gets called, but then there's always an error in the last line: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
 public void createDropDownList()  
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        if (id == 8)
         {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "1"));
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "2"));
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "3"));
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Four", "4"));
            this.pnlChannel.Controls.Add(ddl);
        }
    }
```

Is my .Controls not right?

Comment: Where do you add it to the panel? The panel is in the MasterPage, are you adding the dropdownlist in the page? Why do you add it programmatically at all?

Comment: What does the debugger say? Which object does not have an instance? Your panel or your dropdownlist?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am adding thedropdownlist to the panel which I created in the masterpage. I only want to have it visible if the id is 8.

Comment: @Mivaweb it doesn't say which one, it only occurs if the code is running

Comment: @aha364636 if you only want to have it visible if the id is 8, then add the dropdown manually and then in your codebehind do someting like `this.ddlList.Visible = (id == 8);`

Comment: @aha364636: then dont create and add it programmatically but simply make it visible when the id is8. `ddl.Visible = Request.QueryString["id"] == "8"`. If you add it in the page you can't use `this.pnlChannel`, the you have to use `((MasterClassName)this.Master).pnlChannel`. But that would be a really bad approach.

Comment: Is `createDropDownList()` in master or content page code behind?

Comment: @nelek It is in masterpage codebehind

Comment: Sorry for bothering with questions but, do You call (redirect) that master page from some another page? @Tim if he use `((MasterClassName)this.Master).pnlChannel` then `createDropDownList()` must be in content page... or I wrong?

Comment: @TimSchmelter So it would work if I do it like that?((MasterClassName)this.Master).pnlChannel.Controls.Add(ddl);

Comment: @aha364636: it could work but is very bad for at least two reasons. You are hard-wiring the master with the page and the panel must be `public`(it's protected by default). A little bit better would be to provide a property in your master. Why do you need to add the dropdown from your page to your master at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because my page where I need the Dropdownlist gets generated, so I don't have a file for these sites.

Comment: @aha364636: maybe you don't know it, if you make it `Visible=false` on serverside it means that the HTML isn't rendered at all, so there is no reason to not add it declaratively in the first place. Provide a public property in the Master, f.e. `bool DropDownVisible`, if the argument is `true` the property makes the `DropDownList` visible, otherwise invisible. Then you can call that property form your page in this way: `((MyMaster)this.Master).DropDownVisible = Request.QueryString["id"] == "8"`. But you can also use the master's `Page_Load` event to do it.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you simple thing. Are you supply this `Request.QueryString["id"]` when you test your page? Maybe you can add validation to pass through it if `id` is null or empty.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Where can I find the value of "MyMaster"?

Comment: @aha364636: it's just a pseudo-name since i didn't know the real name of your master-page. Replace it with the name you gave your master-page.

Comment: @TimSchmelter And how do I do the thing with the DropdownVisible? Do I write that inside the masterpage or what do you mean with public property

Comment: @aha364636: yes, in the master-class file.